# 960.gs with 100% JQuery bxSlider

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider, 960.gs

I'm trying to  to extend a the JQuery [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) to 100% of the browser window. I'm using the 960.gs framework for the layout of the rest of my site. The rest of my site needs to be 960px wide but it is essential that my slider will be 100%. I've tried so many CSS combinations but nothing has worked. Has anyone had any luck with this before?

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_4"> LOGO HERE </div>
    <div class="grid_8"> NAVBAR HERE </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li class="slider_image"> <img src="assets/img/banners/hay-banner.jpg" /> </li>
            <li class="slider_image"> <img src="assets/img/banners/smallholders-banner.jpg" /> </li>            
            <li class="slider_image"> <img src="assets/img/banners/tractor-banner.jpg" /> </li>
            <li class="slider_image"> <img src="assets/img/banners/property-owners.jpg" /> </li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> 
<!--END OF JQUERY SLIDER-->
```

I want to try and avoid using multiple containers.

Comment: If it is to be 100% of the grid then put it into a container with `grid_12` class?

Comment: Sorry no, it's 100% of the browser window.

Comment: In which case it has to occur outside of your `container_12`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/CvfRc/19/ Had to changet he class-names a little as I used an existing fiddle with 960.gs